# How to make alphanumeric rules in yii

Tags: php, yii

I need rules for alphanumeric, I need to enter password it must have to be alphanumeric. Can anyone have idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your model class,

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
         array('password', 'compare', 'on'=>"confirmpassword",  'compareAttribute'=>'password'),
         array('password','passwordalphanumeric','on'=>'changepassword'), 
   );
}

// Check password with alphanumeric validation
public function passwordalphanumeric($attribute_name,$params){
     if(!empty($this->password)){
          if (preg_match('~^[a-z0-9]*[0-9][a-z0-9]*$~i',$this->password)) {
                // $subject is alphanumeric and contains at least 1 number
     } else { // failed
          $this->addError($attribute_name,'Please enter password with digits');
     } 
}
```

(or)

you can use [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/alpha/) extension too.

Comment: did you used extension?

Comment: No, i used your function passwordalphanumeric.